# Will there be problems trying to run bootcamp with third party ssd macbook air 2012 upgrade on Catalina 10.15.6?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, ssd

I bought an adapter

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07NSFY5XM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

and a 1tb ssd

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B073SB2MXT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

to put in a 2012 macbook air 10.15.6, didn't buy it to install Windows 10 but would be nice, but then I read many anecdotal posts about third party ssds causing blue screens and failing to install from bootcamp, and messing up both the windows and mac partitions.

So I'm a little wary to try boot camp, but these posts seem to be from years ago before the latest Catalina supplemental update, maybe something got fixed, is it worth a shot?

Vmware and running win2usb or similar program from external hdd don't seem viable because the system is too underpowered with 4gb ram, and only usb 3 ports to work with hard drives/thumb drives, loading MacOS clone drives was very slow when I tried it.

What exactly would cause the problem if I tried to bootcamp my new ssd? Could it be fixed? OWC drives (3x more expensive, not worth it imo) seem to be able to do it with some sort of firmware and software fix.

here are some links to people discussing problems with third party drives and bootcamp.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250349961

https://www.reddit.com/r/bootcamp/comments/ginwlv/bootcamp_with_third_party_ssd/

https://www.reddit.com/r/bootcamp/comments/er9fw7/bootcampsamsung_evo_860_ssd_error_windows_cannot/

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251701019

the last one is recent, me talking to a guy on apple forums who seems knowledgeable who is pretty adamant it cannot be done, but other threads I have read show people doing workarounds, for example:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250921449

but every macbook is different, so I'm not sure I should bother trying.

Comment: Can you post a link to where you read those posts.  A lot of people with little to no experience post things and without seeing it first hand it’s next to impossible  to confirm or refute a claim.  Additionally, it’s even more impossible to solve hypothetical problems based on hypothetical claims - do you have an actual problem to solve?  And (hypothetically speaking), if Bootcamp is problematic, are  you going to stick with that older drive or do something else?

Comment: I added some links to some posts, I suppose there isn't a problem to solve until I get and install my ssd and try to install bootcamp and it didn't work, but from these links it looks like it might not work, if it doesn't work, I'll stick with the new drive for MacOS and just abandon the bootcamp idea, but that would be unfortunate.

Comment: It's just as I thought - people assuming issues without *proof* but because (likely) the last thing they did was get the 3rd party SSD, it somehow *must* be the issue.  ***Corrrelation ≠ Causation***  What I'm seeing here is likely a driver issue with Windows 10.  Remember, you're using a 2012 MacBook Pro and Apple likely hasn't made Windows 10 drivers available for it.  Also, keep in mind, NVMe wasn't a thing back then.  Personally, I've never been a fan of BC and opted to either virtualize or remote desktop to a [NUC](https://intel.ly/3gkmp6q) or other USFF PC.

Comment: yeah, lots of different experiences out there, I'll probably try boot camp myself and if it doesn't work that's ok, I would like to run virtualization like parallels but 4gb ram it probably would be sluggish.